# Should I allow search engines to index user pages where the page language is determined by the language of the browser?

Tags: seo, internationalization, language, technical-seo, accept-language

I have a multilingual project. In this project, the language pages are in `/tr` and `/en` subdirectories before logging into the site. However, after logging into the site, they are all in the `/home` directory and this `/home` directory is not allowed to be indexed.

However, users' profiles can be viewed without logging into the site. For example, if the username is Sultan, the page will be `/sultan` and the language of this page will change according to the language of the browser.

Should I allow this page to be indexed?  I'm concerned because the language will be set automatically on the user page ie `/sultan` page and users can view the page without logging in? Will I run into any SEO issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is multilingual, the proper way to tell Google and Yandex about this is via the HTML `hreflang` attribute.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions

**Important:** Google and Yandex use `hreflang`, Bing and Baidu use [content-language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language).

If you've done this, then you can safely index.

You should also make sure that Google can properly find your pages that require a login to access.

Comment: I don't think using hrefling is a possibility if the same URL can serve multiple languages based on the language requested by the browser.

Comment: It's not...with their current config, but _it is_ the correct method of handling internationalization...which is my point! Perhaps I could be clearer, will look in AM.

Pages in example.com/en/* and example.com/es/* must separate with referencing hreflangs. One URL get's indexed in the states, the other in Spain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already going to use hreflang on /tr and /en pages. But how should I go about the pages where I use the browser language automatically?

Comment: Google recommends using different URLs for each language version of a page rather than using cookies or browser settings to adjust the content language on the page.

I would recommend that you not use the browser language to determine language automatically, and instead create unique pages for all of the languages that you support. This is because Googlebot originates from the USA and sends HTTP requests without setting `Accept-Language` in the request header.